# DBContext.Set<T> does not contain definition of Set<T>

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am trying to implement an abstract repository pattern as described in [**THIS**](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/generic-repository-pattern-entity-framework-asp-net-mvc-and-unit-testing-triangle) post. I'm getting the error message

> 'C' does not contain a definition for 'Set' and no extension method
>   'Set'  accepting a first argument of type 'C' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

where `C` is the DBContext

```
namespace Rental.Data.Entity.Repository
{
   public abstract class GenericRepo<C, T> : 
       IGenericRepo<T> where T : class where C : RentalContainer, new()
   {
       private C _DBContext = new C();
       protected C DBContext
       {

           get { return _DBContext; }
           set { _DBContext = value; }
       }

       public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
       {       

           IQueryable<T> query = _DBContext.Set<T>(); <-- here is gives the error
           return query;
       }
```

---

yet another update

```
public partial class RentalContainer : ObjectContext
    {
        #region Constructors

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new RentalContainer object using the connection string found in the 'RentalContainer' section of the application configuration file.
        /// </summary>
        public RentalContainer() : base("name=RentalContainer", "RentalContainer")
        {
            this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
            OnContextCreated();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initialize a new RentalContainer object.
        /// </summary>
        public RentalContainer(string connectionString) : base(connectionString, "RentalContainer")
        {
            this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
            OnContextCreated();
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ObjectContext` does not have a `Set` method. It has `CreateObjectSet` method

```
   public abstract class GenericRepo<C, T> : IGenericRepo<T> 
     where T : class 
     where C : RentalContainer, new()
   {
       private C _DBContext = new C();
       protected C DBContext
       {

           get { return _DBContext; }
           set { _DBContext = value; }
       }

       public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
       {       

           IQueryable<T> query = _DBContext.CreateObjectSet<T>();
           return query;
       }
   }
```

Comment: my database context is renamed as `RentalContainer`

Comment: wait i'll update the question, its created by default when i added the `edmx`

Comment: @john Updated answer. Use `CreateObjectSet` method instead of `Set` method.

Comment: is `CreateObjectSet` the the new way of `Set`, or Set is deprecated or something

Comment: @john `Set` method belongs to `DbContext` class which is part of EF 4.1 and `CreateObjectSet` belongs to `ObjectContext` in EF 4.0

Comment: @john the tutorial uses the `DbContext` class and you are using `ObjectContext` class. Please go through MSDN to check the APIs

Answer (score 2):

Add reference to EntityFramework.dll

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679544(v=vs.103).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Press `ctrl` + `.` and use `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;` I had to add. But I got this error when I accidentally created an empty class named `DbContext`.

The solution for me is to delete the empty `DbContext class` and add the correct using line to `DbContext`. (using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your DataContext class extends DBContext