# Create generic abstract class using EF database first approach

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, c#-4.0, abstract-class

I have some similar entities and I want to create a generic abstract class for `CRUD` operations for them, but I don't know how can access to entities in generic class. For example:

```
public abstract class HeaderRepository<T>
{
    public HeaderRepository()
    {

    }

    public virtual byte[] Insert(T item)
    {
        using (MyEntities context = new MyEntities())
        {
            context.*****  <-- What I should write to add an object to entity T
        }
    }
}
```

I hope I've got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your DB set. It would be better to have a private variable at class level, set in the constructor and then use it.

```
using (MyEntities context = new MyEntities())
    {
        DbSet<T> dbSet = context.Set<T>();
        dbSet.Add(...) //Whatever your operation is. 
    }
```

Comment: Because I use `ObjectContext` I got this error: 'MyEntities' does not contain a definition for 'Set' and no extension method 'Set' accepting a first argument of type 'MyEntities' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248460/dbcontext-sett-does-not-contain-definition-of-sett

Comment: Sorry But can you explain more? I don't know what change should I apply

Comment: Try replacing set<T> with CreateObjectSet<T>

Comment: I wrote this: `var query = context.CreateObjectSet<T>();` but got this error:  The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>()'

Comment: public abstract class HeaderRepository<T> needs to be public abstract class HeaderRepository<T>  where T : class